# Inserting json column in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a JSON that I want to insert into BQ. The column data type is STRING. Here is the sample JSON value.

```
"{\"a\":\"#\",\"b\":\"b value\"}"
```

This is a bulk load from a CSV file.

The error I'm getting is

```
Error: Data between close double quote (\") and field separator."; Reason: "invalid"},Invalid {Location: ""; Message: "Error while reading data, error message: CSV processing encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 0; errors: 1; max bad: 0; error percent: 0"; Reason: "invalid"}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is an issue with how you escape the double quotes.
I could reproduce the issue you describe, and fixed it by escaping the double quotes with `"` instead of a backslash `\`:

```
"{""a"":""#"",""b"":""b value""}"
```

This information is well-hidden in the doc [there](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#csv-options) (in the "Quote" section):

> For example, if you want to escape the default character ' " ', use ' "" '.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this data comes from a third party and I can't really change the data in any form. 

I agree with your answer that changing \ with " using sed can do the job but I don't have the privilege of doing so.

Comment: Ouch.. if you can't change the format of have the third party changing it for you, what about uploading your file to GCS instead and trigger the modification in the cloud (with Cloud Run for instance)?